# Has anyone researched this variant of separable rational connectedness?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, rational-curves

If I am correct, then one of the definitions of rational chain connectedness is that a variety $ X $ is rationally chain connected if

1) there are schemes $ \mathcal{C} $ and $ T $ with a flat, proper map $ \pi: \mathcal{C} \to T $ such that all fibres $ \pi $ of closed points of $ T $ are connected rational curves,

2) there is a map $ f: \mathcal{C} \to X $ such that $ (f,f): \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to X \times X $ is dominant.

Rational chain connectedness of a smooth variety in characteristic zero implies rational connectedness.  Generally when it comes to concepts like uniruledness, rational connectedness, and unirationality, in positive characteristic separability is the main obstruction to any of the theorems one might like to see hold working.  If one adds the appropriate separability condition then such theorems generally work, e.g., a separably uniruled variety $ X $ has the property that the plurigenera vanish, while a uniruled variety does not necessarily have this property.

Has anyone thought of changing the above definition by adding the requirement that the map $ f $ is Etale and that the map $ \pi $ be smooth of relative dimension $ \dim(\mathcal{C}) -\dim(T) $?  If a variety satisfying this condition is ``separably rationally chain connected'' (assuming that this term does not denote something else), then has anyone looked into trying to prove that a smooth variety is separably rationally chain connected if and only if it is separably rationally connected?  Thank you.